Issues with opencv-android (4.10.0) and a specific version of Kotlin(2.0.0). It's not working
I am recently working on an opencv android application, and I am facing some issues regarding that:
opencv-android version 4.10.0
This version completely works fine with Kotlin version 1.9.0.
But it has an error for Kotlin version 2.0.0.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.arpit.test"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.arpit.test"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    implementation(project(":openCV"))
}



apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

def openCVersionName = "4.10.0"
def openCVersionCode = ((4 * 100 + 10) * 100 + 0) * 10 + 0

println "OpenCV: " +openCVersionName + " " + project.buildscript.sourceFile

android {
    namespace 'org.opencv'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 34

        versionCode openCVersionCode
        versionName openCVersionName

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"
                targets "opencv_jni_shared"
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
            }
        }
        release {
            packagingOptions {
                doNotStrip '**/*.so'  // controlled by OpenCV CMake scripts
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        prefabPublishing true
        buildConfig true
    }
    prefab {
        opencv_jni_shared {
            headers "native/jni/include"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['native/libs']
            java.srcDirs = ['java/src']
            res.srcDirs = ['java/res']
            manifest.srcFile 'java/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

    publishing {
        singleVariant('release') {
            withSourcesJar()
            withJavadocJar()
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path (project.projectDir.toString() + '/libcxx_helper/CMakeLists.txt')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        release(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'org.opencv'
            artifactId = 'opencv'
            version = '4.10.0'

            afterEvaluate {
               from components.release
           }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = 'myrepo'
            url = "${project.buildDir}/repo"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
}


with 2.0.0 I am facing error like:
error message
I have tried same with kotlin version 1.9.0 and it seemed works fine not a problem and i also checked online it says opencv-android supports kotlin version 2.0.0 so can anyone help me get a solution how this works ?

Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. See Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
